# SFINAE-based ifdef

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

**Trivia**

It is safe to use `#ifdef` in case we want the compiler to optimize some part of the code away as shown in what follows.

```
#ifdef LOG
mtmd();
#endif
```

Hence, if `LOG` isn't defined during the compile time, there will be no overhead during execution.

**Question**

I'm interested to realize the same mechanism using SFINAE. A simplified version of the code is shown in what follows.

```
template <bool cond, typename std::enable_if<cond>::type* = nullptr>
inline void log(void (*func)(int, int), int in, int out) {
 (*func)(in, out);
}

template <bool cond, typename std::enable_if<!cond>::type* = nullptr>
inline void log(void (*func)(int, int), int in, int out) {}
```

I can use it in the following form.

```
void mtmd(int x, int y) { /* Do something */}

int main() {
  constexpr cond = true; // or flase
  int x, y;
  log<cond>(&mtmd, x, y);
}
```

The question is, when `cond` is `false` is there going to be any overhead or the compiler optimizes everything away since the `log` function is `inline`?

Comment: You are still converting the lambda into a std::function (when constructing a std::function heap space is allocated)  even when cond is false.   You would need to ditch the lambda and std::function and just use a function pointer.  https://www.godbolt.org/z/tAaL4o   You were probably hoping that you could use bind to pass parameters without log knowing...  The other thing you could do is use an implementation of a function object that doesn't put anything on the heap - maybe something like https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible.

Comment: `if constexpr` added in C++17 would be my way to go instead of SFINAE (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if)

Comment: Thank you @JerryJeremiah for your comment. I changed to code accordingly (have to pass parameters to the function tho.). Can you please kindly share your thoughts on the revised code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general one can never be sure with `inline` if it will work since it is more of a clue for the compiler than a real requirement (in the matter of the inlining of course, in matter of linkage and variables it is pretty strict). Of course it is highly probable that compiler will optimize away unnecessary calls to `log` but it is not required by the standard. As said in [cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline)

> Since this meaning of the keyword inline is non-binding, compilers are
>   free to use inline substitution for any function that's not marked
>   inline, and are free to generate function calls to any function marked
>   inline.

To be sure you would have to use `__forceinline` compiler extension